# How to redirect all requests from /zf3/* URI to index_zf3.php file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I am working in a *slow* migration from Zend Framework 1 to Zend Framework 3. Right now I need to have both working side by side so the way I found to achieve this was using an `.htacess` file to redirect the ZF1 requests to it's front controller and same with ZF3 requests. So far this is what I have done:

```
RewriteRule ^legacy(/.*)?$ index_zf3.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sw(/.*)?$ index_zf3.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^application(/.*)?$ index_zf3.php [NC,L]
```

The rules above means legacy, sw and application are being built in ZF3. The approach works but now I am moving more and more code so ZF3 URL (requests) are growing up and it means I'll need to keep adding rules each time and I don't want to.

Currently the directory structure is as follow:

I want to redirect all the requests going to`/zf3/<any_controller_name>/<any_parameters>` to `index_zf3.php`

What's the right rule for achieve this?

Comment: The same as the other three? It's obvious you already know how to do this, so I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to ask?

Comment: @MichaelHampton _What's the right rule for achieve this?_ that's my question

Comment: You already know how to do this! So that can't possibly be your question.